# Vuetify switchers side-by-side on right

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I am using vuetify 3 with vuejs 3, and I am trying to create 3 switchers side by side on the right side:

[image]

```
<template>
  <v-card variant="outlined" class="pa-6 ma-3" color="#BDBDBD">
    <v-row class="pa- ma-0">
      <v-btn
        color="primary"
        class="mr-2"
        :loading="loading"
        :disabled="loading"
      >
        Atualizar
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn color="error" :disabled="selected.length == 0" class="mr-2">
        Plotar
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn color="warning" :disabled="selected.length == 0" class="mr-3">
        Favoritar
      </v-btn>
      <v-row class="ml-3 black-label">
        <v-switch
          label="Intraday"
          v-model="intraday"
          color="primary"
          hide-details
        ></v-switch>
        <v-switch
          label="Stocks"
          v-model="stocks"
          color="primary"
          hide-details
        ></v-switch>
        <v-switch
          label="Favorites"
          v-model="favorites"
          color="primary"
          hide-details
        ></v-switch>
      </v-row>
    </v-row>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'
  const search = ref('')
  const selected = ref([])
  const intraday = ref(false)
  const favorites = ref(false)
  const stocks = ref(false)
  const loading = ref(false)
  const msg = ref('Hello World!')
</script>
```

[Reproducible example](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

I've tried to change v-switch class to mr-3 as I did with buttons, but I couldn't get the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just remove the v-row elements (I don't think they should be nested anyway), and create your layout manually:

```html
  <v-card>
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-space-between align-center">
      <div>
        button declarations...
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex" style="gap: 20px">
        switch declarations...
      </div>
    </div>
  </v-card>
```

- `d-flex` turns the container into a flexbox, so the two containers sit next to each other and we can use flex alignment.
- `flex-wrap` allows the box to put the second container on a new line when there is not enough space.
- `justify-space-between` will put unused space between the items (this is what pushes the switches to the right).
- `align-center` will center the content vertically.

Here it is in a [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)